AWS Amplify URL signature version 4
I had been using Amplify version 4, I am currently updating Amplify to versioni 6. With in my code I need a signed URL for my websocket connection to be established. I have a cognito user and use the credentials to create the signed URL.
My original code:
const userCredentials = await Auth.currentUserCredentials();

const accessInfo = {
       access_key: userCredentials.accessKeyId,
       secret_key: userCredentials.secretAccessKey,
       session_token: userCredentials.sessionToken,
};


        //- Sign Url
       return Signer.signUrl(sourceUrl, accessInfo);

This would return a string signed URL.
Signer was a part of Amplify version 4 but I no longer have access to it in version 6. This is causing problems in my websocket connection since I can not get back the correct signed URL.
I am currently trying to user the following code but the URL I get back is wrong and is not a string.
        const {
            tokens,
            credentials,
            identityId,
            userSub
        } = await fetchAuthSession();


        const url = new URL(sourceUrl);

        // Create an HttpRequest from the URL
        const request = new HttpRequest({
            method: 'GET', // or 'PUT' if you are uploading to S3 for example
            protocol: url.protocol,
            hostname: url.hostname,
            path: url.pathname,
            headers: {
                'host': url.hostname
            }
        });

            const signer = new SignatureV4({
                credentials: credentials,
                region: 'us-east-1',
                service: 'execute-api', 
                sha256: Sha256 
            });

     const signedRequest = await signer.sign(request);

Is there a way to get a signed URL the same way as Amplify version 4?
